# How to remove image caches when app closed?

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, image-caching, imagedownload

I have successfully downloaded images with image caches.
I want to remove all image caches when i close the app also want that when the app goes in background state any one have idea how can i do that?

Comment: When app goes to background applicationDidEnterBackground method will get called you can do some processing there

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in `- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application` that is an `UIApplication`'s delegate method and executed on your app upon entering the background.